# What make and model carburetor does a Farmall H tractor have?

Tags: carburetor, tractor

I've been asked to find parts for a Farmall H Tractor carb.

None of the searches I try identify the Make and Model.

I believe the engine is an IH C152. I can see that the same carb is used on an H, HV & W4.

Did Farmall make their own? or are they OEM Holley/Zenith etc

I can't inspect it myself but have been told the main jet has been damaged and repaired in the past. Im trying to find out what it is do i can make enquiries about parts before i get there.

Comment: Ugh. After much delay the tractor engine turned out to be a Farmall M. (In a Hamilton grader conversion.) Carb was stripped and cleaned and torn gaskets replaced and it is now running again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They used different manufacturers and models of carburetors through the years, or it could have been replaced with a different kind. You are best to pull the carb and gently clean it to find mfg or model numbers stamped into the throttle base or on a tag

http://www.steinertractor.tv/Wrenching-with-Rachel/How-to-identify-your-carburetor/189272--3848536

Comment: Im not able to get my hands on the tractor myself. Ive been told the main jet has been 'mangled'... so i was hoping to find either a carb kit or a whole replacement before i start work on it.

Comment: I see its possible to buy a new replacement carb, but that seems excessive. If i can identify it i hope to find a 2nd hand carb or a kit.

Comment: @Peter let us know how it goes.